# Get NoClassDefFoundError when connecting to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, e-commerce

I get these type of errors

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/Mongo
Controller.ConnectMongoDB.connectDB(ConnectMongoDB.java:8)
Controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:44)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: You should show what kind of code you have.

Comment: can you please explain more and provide code for database connection.